# Windows scheduled task doesn't trigger for an action defined

Tags: windows, powershell, service, scheduled-tasks

Following Windows task scheduler task is configured to trigger when there is an event ID `7034` recorded by source `Service Control Manager` in the `System` event log. But it doesn't getting trrigered, is there something I'm missing?

Task config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2023-12-04T14:47:47.0078594</Date>
    <Author>domain\author</Author>
    <URI>\ReviveDeadService</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <EventTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Subscription>&lt;QueryList&gt;&lt;Query Id="0" Path="System"&gt;&lt;Select Path="System"&gt;*[System[Provider[@Name='Service Control Manager'] and EventID=7034]]&lt;/Select&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryList&gt;</Subscription>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-2969236542-3715907981-188815748-53088</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>powershell.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File "D:\Scripts\ReviveDeadService.ps1" -ServiceName  myservice_4343</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Event from system event log:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2/7/2024 11:43:23 AM
Event ID:      7034
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      mycomputer.com
Description:
The Agent Listener on port 4343 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 3 time(s).
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7034</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-07T19:43:23.630202700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>182814</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="664" ThreadID="5796" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>mycomputer.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Agent Listener on port 4343</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">3</Data>
    <Binary>6800760072006100670065006E0074006C0069007300740065006E00650072005F0034003300340033000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The action script `D:\Scripts\ReviveDeadService.ps1` has simple service start command. But I don't see this task is even triggered from the task history.

The flow is like this,
`Service goes down -> Event recorded to system log -> Triggers task scheduler task to execute ReviveDeadService.ps1`

*While, the flow works as expected if I simulate the event using following command, but not when it naturally happens.*

```
Write-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "Service Control Manager" -EventID 7034 -Message "The Agent Listener on port 4343 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 3 time(s)." -EntryType Error
```

Appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: i have had this issue recently  first thing to do is to manually start and stop your service if this is done successfully then it might be authorization issue if not then your service is having issue; but from the log your task scheduler handled it perfectly

Comment: if you can add you service code it will be great to see if everything is okay there

Comment: Thank you @OyinladeDemola for checking, sorry if I didn't present my issue correctly. I was looking to trigger the scheduled task when the service goes down. The event/event log I have added is when the service went down, from my task scheduler log I didn't even see it got triggered. btw, this is a third party service, so no access to the code base. The idea is `Service goes down -> Event recorded to system log -> Triggers task scheduler task to bring the service back online`

Comment: i think (not sure) i understood you but what am saying is manually start the service and stop it then check the system log again if you will see thesame error

Comment: It doesn't record the same event or any other error events if I stop and start it manually. It is back to running state.